# to wonder versus to ask onself - are these really synonyms?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I  came across either of them meaning guesswork , consequently I'm more than confused.  Tried several sources to get it.

Would like you to re-open it:)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between to wonder vs. to ask oneself meaning guesswork- does "to ask oneself" exist?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/424589/difference-between-to-wonder-vs-to-ask-oneself-meaning-guesswork-does-to-ask)